# Comparing and delete api data

Tags: python, django

I have a django project that takes in some data from another app of ours. The data looks like this:

```
{u'   updated':   u'2017-04-03T22:30:53.760278   Z',
   u'added':   u'2017-04-03T22:30:53.760197   Z',
   u'name':u'Jean Lamb,
   1942-   ', u'   authority':{  
      u'id':2,
      u'added_by':2,
      u'name':u'VIAF'
   },
   u'local_identifier':u'85363862',
   u'concept_type':{  
      u'id':5,
      u'identifier':      u'viaf:personal',
      u'name':u'',
      u'description':None
   },
   u'identifier':   u'http://viaf.org/viaf/85363862',
   u'identities':[  
      {  
         u'part_of':{  
            u'id':1,
            u'added_by':2,
            u'name':            u'builtin:Conceptpower'
         },
         u'added':         u'2017-04-03T22:33:20.476637         Z',
         u'name':u'Jean Lamb',
         u'confidence':1.0,
         u'updated':         u'2017-04-03T22:33:20.476699         Z',
         u'concepts':[  
            u'http://viaf.org/viaf/85363862',
            u'http://www.digitalhps.org/concepts/CONpeSHC70qxNC0'
         ],
         u'id':208,
         u'added_by':{  
            u'username':u'erickjones',
            u'email':u'erick.jones@example.com'
         }
      },
      {  
         u'part_of':{  
            u'id':1,
            u'added_by':2,
            u'name':            u'builtin:Conceptpower'
         },
         u'added':         u'2017-04-03T22:35:02.546054         Z',
         u'name':u'Jean Lamb',
         u'confidence':1.0,
         u'updated':         u'2017-04-03T22:35:02.546116         Z',
         u'concepts':[  
            u'http://viaf.org/viaf/85363862',
            u'http://www.digitalhps.org/concepts/CONpeSHC70qxNC0'
         ],
         u'id':209,
         u'added_by':{  
            u'username':u'erickjones',
            u'email':u'erick.jones@example.com'
         }
      },
```

Right now I have a function that goes through and compares the concepts in in the identities. What I want to do is delete the duplicate concepts. The nesting of the dictionaries and lists are throwing me off. What I have been trying is:

```
del results[i]["identities"][z]["concepts"]
```

Any ideas as to why this does not work?

Here is my loop incase anyone is interested:

```
while (i != di):
    test = results[i]["identities"]
    if results[i]["identities"]:
        z = 0
        while (z != len(results[i]["identities"])):
            con1 = results[i]["identities"][z]["concepts"]
            print "this is con1: %s", con1
            if z != len(results[i]["identities"]):
                z = z + 1
            else:
                break
            if z != len(results[i]["identities"]):
                con2 = results[i]["identities"][z]["concepts"]
                print "this is con2: %s", con2
                if set(con1) == set(con2):


                   del results[i]["identities"][z]["concepts"]

            else:
                break


    i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

In this line,

```
if set(con1) and set(con2):
```

Do you intend to check if con1 and con2 are the same set? Shouldn't you use == operator?

Comment: You are correct my mistake. Changing the comparison does not solve my problem unfortunately though